# Branch.io Cordova API - init() fails on Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, branch.io

I'm having problems getting Branch.io to work in a Cordova powered Android app. I have a landing page that parses the data from branch.io deep links and forwards the user to the correct page. My javascript for this page contains:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  console && console.log("Device Ready");
  initBranch();
}

function initBranch() {
  branch.init(<branchKey>, function(err, data) {

    console && console.log("branch init error: " + err);

    //then the parsing and forwarding follows - omitted here
}
```

I then created a Branch.io deep link to this landing page in the web api and tested it in chrome which works.

Then i tried to move to the Cordova app...

I followed this guide to prepare the app for branch.io:
https://dev.branch.io/recipes/quickstart_guide/cordova/ (I installed the plugin and adapted the Manifest file.)

But when i try to open the same link that worked in chrome on my Android device the app opens correctly and the landing page loads, but i'm not forwared. Instead i see the following error in logcat:

```
I/chromium(19382): [INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Device Ready"
[...]
I/chromium(19382): [INFO:CONSOLE(29)] "branch init error: Error: API request /v1/open missing parameter device_fingerprint_id"
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? I'm just getting to know Cordova and Branch.io so it's probably something small i'm overlooking.

Thanks,
Lif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine figured it out:

Branch.io creates an entry branch_session in the local storage of the android device. On my device this session was corrupted *somehow* and the device_fingerprint_id was empty:

```
{"session_id":"198413861345316824","identity_id":"198398707320770300","device_fingerprint_id":null,"browser_fingerprint_id":null,"link":"<link>","data":"{\"+is_first_session\":false,\"+clicked_branch_link\":false}"}
```

After clearing the local storage* the session was freshly created, and now looks like this:

```
{"session_id":"198413861345316824","identity_id":"198398707320770300","device_fingerprint_id":"118176839880411216","browser_fingerprint_id":null,"link":<link>,"data":"{\"+is_first_session\":false,\"+clicked_branch_link\":false}"}
```

And now deep linking works.

Kr,
Lif

* *To clear the local storage i used chrome://inspect --> inspect webview, go to resources tab, choose "local storage" and the the correct url, then remove all values.*